# contar o mostrar todos los registros php

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

he estado creando un sitio con un mvc propio. Quiero que retorne el numero de usuarios o me los devulva. este es el código.

```
public function getAllUsers(){
        $QuerySql = "SELECT id, username, email, created_on, role FROM users";
        $query = $this->_con->prepare($QuerySql);
        $query->execute();
        $object = new stdClass();
        foreach($query->fetch() as $key => $value) {
         if (is_array($value)) {
          $value = convertToObject($value);
         }
        $object->$key = $value;
      }
       return $object;
    }
```

y quiero que funcione algo así:`

```
<?php 
// devuelve el numero de registros 
echo Auth::getAllUsers()->count;
// o tambien
echo Auth::getAllUSers();
```

Comment: Por favor delimita ya que habría variaciones en tu consulta, ¿qué tratas de hacer?, mostrar las filas recuperadas o el conteo de filas

Comment: ambas quiero decir, si pongo getAllUsers()->count las cuente y si solo retorne todo

Comment: Es muy mala idea leer todos los usuarios para luego devolver solo el total, vas a consumir recursos innecesariamente. En caso de querer continuar con lo mismo, almacena los resultados en una propiedad de la clase, devuelve la instancia de la clase `return $this;` y crea el método count, donde vas a devolver solo el total de los resultados almacenados previamente.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar debes tener en cuenta que para que funcione con :: una clase cualquiera, debería ser un método estático.

En segundo lugar para que getAllUsers()->count funcione el resultado de getAllUsers debería incluir una propiedad count.